# HTTP Status 404 : The requested resource is not available

Tags: jsf, servlets, web.xml, myfaces, apache-tomee

i've a dynamic web project that depends on another project.
I use TomEE server in eclipse (tomEE web-profile 1.7.4) e the server starts normally, but opens this page:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /dlms-frontend/

type: Status report

message: /dlms-frontend/

description: The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.68 (1.7.4)
```

this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>DLMS-frontend</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

I don't know why because yesterday before doing some changes on other files,this configurations worked fine.
I've looked other questions but the problem wasn't the same.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

Did you check eclipse redeployed properly? Wtp messes up the delivery sometimes. Also check logs for errors

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer in my opinion

Comment: Not sure, concretely not using eclipse WTP which is buggy with tomcat/tomee is an actual solution but rarely done cause it is nice to use the IDE instead of a maven plugin or other alternatives. "I don't know why because yesterday before doing some changes on other files,this configurations worked fine." really tends to correlate this.

Comment: I agree that WTP (or rather the server 'plugins' in it) cause this sometimes. But asking to check things is not the answer. Ask in comments and if the OP confirms this solved it, create an answer that 'explicitly' state that WTP caused it in this case.